# What is the best way to guess the value of x+y?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search

The problem is simple when we only want to guess one number. For example, we would like to guess x and we know that the highest possible value is n. We can do binary search, of which complexity is O(log n).

However, I have found the variation of this problem:

Given 0<x<n and 0<y<m, how to find x+y with the smallest number of queries?

Supposed that the guess is z, we can ask the questioner to compare with the other value and he will tell the relationship between z and the other value - i.e. less than, equal to or greater than. The possible comparisons are:

(1) comparing x, and z.

(2) comparing y, and z.

(3) comparing x+y, and z.

In my opinion, we can just do binary search on (x+y). Therefore, time complexity is O( log(m+n)). This is better than finding x, then finding y, of which complexity is O(log m + log n) = O(log mn)

However, I am curious whether there is any better solution than doing binary search on x+y.

Thank you very much for your help.

---

edit:
So the questioner firstly thinks of the number x, and the number y, and then he asks the answerer what is the value of x+y. The answerer can make three queries as shown above. My question is how can the answerer find the answer with the minimum number of queries.

Comment: Binary search has complexity O(log(n))

Comment: `Given 0<x<n and 0<y<m, how to find x+y with the smallest number of queries?`  What? Are you trying to find any two numbers such that their sum equals some other number with those constraints?

Comment: Funny thing about logs: log (m n) = log m + log n <= 2 log max(m, n) <= 2 log (m + n), so the asymptotic complexities are the same. One standard approach for obtaining lower bounds is to use the fact that, for a deterministic strategy, the sequence of responses determines the questions. Thus, there must be a one-to-one map from answers into response sequences.

Comment: @NiklasB. Before your edit you said "We can do binary search, of which complexity is O(n)."

Comment: @Mene Yes, each time we make the query, the questioner will tell if the answer is too high or too low. So that's why i suggested that we can do binary search on x+y. But, I am curious if there is a better way than this as there are three possible queries that can be done.

Comment: It's certainly possible to do a little bit better in some cases; if m = n = 4, then two queries, x ? 2 and y ? 2, suffice to recover x + y, whereas binary search on x + y requires three in the worst case.

Comment: @FiveFiftyFive: binary search is optimal when each possiblity has an equal probability.  That is the case for `x`, and for `y`, but is _NOT_ the case for `x+y`.  Optimal would be something similar to but not quite a binary search. Still working on the details.  (On the other hand, the optimal search I was thinking of is still O(log(m+n)), it'd simply be faster _on average_.

Comment: @Mooing for that to work you need to assume distributions of x and y... those are not specified in the question

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Will this really make difference when n and m are very large?

Comment: Probably not. No intelligent strategy should need more than two "equal" responses, which, by a fairly lazy application of the technique that I mentioned earlier, gives a lg (m + n) - c lg lg (m + n) worst-case lowerbound for some not-too-large c. I would be surprised if that gap couldn't be tightened to O(1).

Answer (score 3):

Binary search is optimal when each possibility has an equal probability. That is the case for x, and for y, but is NOT the case for x+y. A strategy that gets fewest guesses on average would be something similar to but not quite a binary search.

With a binary search, all possibilities are equally probable

```
probability |                                                    |
            | [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] |
            | [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] |
            | [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] |
            |_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_|
              0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

We guess the middle, and discard half the probable answers:

```
probability |                       V  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X  X |
            | [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] |
            | [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] |
            | [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] |
            |_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_|
              0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

All remainig answers are still equally probable so we can simply recurse.

When finding x+y where x and y are each randomly selected from a uniform probability range, the probability of each x+y is NOT equally probable.

```
probability |                          V                      |
            |                         []                      |
            |                      [] [] []                   |
            |                   [] [] [] [] []                |
            |                [] [] [] [] [] [] []             |
            |             [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []          |
            |          [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []       |
            |       [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []    |
            |____[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_|
              0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Obviously, guessing the middle is still the best first guess:

```
probability |                          V  X  X  X  X  X  X  X |
            |                         []                      |
            |                      [] [] []                   |
            |                   [] [] [] [] []                |
            |                [] [] [] [] [] [] []             |
            |             [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []          |
            |          [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []       |
            |       [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []    |
            |____[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_[]_|
              0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15
```

But what's not intuitive is where to guess next.  In the diagram above the best guess after 8 would be 5 or 6 (not 4), but I'm not sure how to calculate that exactly.  If I figure it out I'll let you know.

```
 v = lower_bound
 u = upper_bound
 t = probability(v)
 s = probability(u)
 r = min(s,t)
 p = guess

 (p-v)r+(p-v)^2/2 = (u-p)r+(u-p)^2/2
 pr-rv+(p^2-pv+v^2)/2 = ur-pr+(u^2-up+p^2)/2
 2pr-2rv+p^2-pv+v^2 = 2ur-2pr+u^2-up+p^2
 2pr-2rv+p^2-pv+v^2-2pr+up-p^2 = 2ur+u^2
 2pr+p^2-pv-2pr+up-p^2 = 2ur+u^2+2rv-v^2
 -pv+up = 2ur+u^2+2rv-v^2
 (u-v)p = u^2+2ur+2rv-v^2
 p = (u^2+2ur+2rv-v^2)/(u-v)
```

Nope, that's wrong too.  Still working on it.

[Niklas B. observed that everything in this answer assumes that x and y are both picked uniformly from their range.  If that is not a safe assumption, then yes, binary search is fastest on average]

Comment: The visualization is very clear. But, considering the probability, instead of binary search, which algorithm should we use?

Comment: "How to calculate it exactly" Use Knuth's quadratic-time dynamic program for computing an optimal binary search tree with given access frequencies?

Comment: @FiveFiftyFive: I was thinking something like a binary search except you pick something _toward_ the middle of the origional range rather than _exactly_ between the min and max, but I'm having trouble calculating exactly what one should guess.  David: I have no idea what that is, but sounds like it makes sense.

Comment: You select a pivot such that the area under the remaining probability density is halfed. If you assume uniform distributions, you can use simple geometry to compute the splitting point

Comment: @NiklasB.: That was my thought, but the math behind picking that splitting point is a hair trickier than I'd expected, and I'm simultaneously doing other things.

Comment: @Mooing: In hindsight it's also probably more complicated than that, because it's not clear what to do if the area is not a proper multiple of 2. Setting up an optimal binary search tree as suggested by David can be done in O(n log n) using the Garsia–Wachs algorithm as a preprocessing step, otherwise the approximate area halving is probably a near-optimal strategy